# Obstruction to lifting homomorphism of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, obstruction-theory

Is there a "cohomology" group that encodes obstructions to constructing a lift in a diagram of groups below? If $X\to Y$ is an extension and the bottom row is the identity map it's just $H^1(X;\ker(\beta)).$ The answer obviously comes from some obstruction theory arguments, but I can't pinpoint an exact answer. I guess because I don't understand obstruction theory well enough.

[image]

Comment: could you include the diagram in the post?

Comment: A quick remark : if $\alpha$ is injective with projective cokernel and $\beta$ is surjective, resp. if $\alpha$ is injective and $\beta$ is surjective with injective kernel then the lift exists.

Comment: @AdrienMORIN What do you mean with projective/injective for non-abelian groups?

Comment: Even quicker remark: in $Grp$ projective objects are exactly free groups and injective one is trivial.

Comment: Ah sorry, I assumed everything was abelian. My bad.